# jstree AJAX doesn't work, has a Syntax error: unrecognized expression for the json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jstree

I use the jstree API to request the json data with AJAX, but it doesn't work, and it shows me the error:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
{"results":[{"id":"a","parent":"b","text":"hello","icon":"something..."},
{"id":"b","parent":"#","text":"world","icon":"somethingelse..."}]}

It seems the json is the right format, but the AJAX cannot recognize it.

My AJAX code like this:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({ 
  'core' : {
      'data' : {
          'url' : 'loadjsTree.php',
          'data' : function (node) {
              return { 'id' : node.id };
          }
      }, 
  }
});
```

And I do like the API demo:[link to the demo](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=%24.jstree.defaults.core.data)

Why it doesn't work? Cound someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried removing the "results" from your object?

{"results":[{"id":"a","parent":"b","text":"hello","icon":"something..."}, {"id":"b","parent":"#","text":"world","icon":"somethingelse..."}]}

to

[{"id":"a","parent":"b","text":"hello","icon":"something..."}, {"id":"b","parent":"#","text":"world","icon":"somethingelse..."}]

The JSON structure for jstree - http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

You could also try adding 'dataType': 'JSON'...

```
'url' : 'loadjsTree.php',
'dataType': 'JSON',
'data' : function (node) {
return { 'id' : node.id };
}
```

I read that it was no longer required but it helped me.

Comment: thank you, I tried to transfer the json to an array, and it works. But I am just want to know if there is some easier way to solve that and don't need to change the format of the json.